# What is the version of C used in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

What is the version of C used in GCC? C99, C11 or C90? I thought was the GCC use C99 but I was mistaken:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  ...
}
```

error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode.

Comment: Use `gcc -std=c99` if you need C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [2 Language Standards Supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards):

> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu90`; this is intended to change to `-std=gnu11` in some future release.

Comment: Time has passed. The linked documentation page now states that "The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu17." This corresponds to C17 with GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default is `-std=gnu90`. You could specify `-std=c99` in your compiler flag to support this.

Answer (score 2):

By default `gcc` uses C90 with [GNU extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), this is all covered in the `gcc` docs [Language Standards Supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), the flag for this would be `-std=gnu90`:

> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu90; this is intended to change to -std=gnu11 in some future release.

If you want C99 support than you should use `-std=c99`, although this does not mean `gcc` will not use extensions, so if you want to receive a warning when `gcc` using an extension you need to add `-pedantic` and `-pedantic-errors` to turn that into an error:

> to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be errors rather than warnings)

Answer (score 0):

Use -std=99

Before C99, you had to define the local variables at the start of a block. C99 imported the C++ feature that you can intermix local variable definitions with the instructions and you can define variables in the for and while control expressions.